# JavaFX: observable model/list & automatic UI refreshing

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I've been trying to make automatic UI refreshing works as in WPF for several days, and to be honest I'm very unhappy with the solutions I found on google because they're mostly hacks / workarounds.

What I want:

- Changes in model lists cause UI change
- Changes in model properties cause UI change
- Changes in model properties propagate to containing lists and cause UI change

The following is what I have currently:

1. Model classes have to be based on ObservableModel.
2. Model classes support manual firing of property changes (no auto-firing yet)
3. Model lists support auto-firing of collection change and property-changes happened in contained items
4. ListView can work directly with ObservableModelList
5. TableView requires each of TableColumn to have cellValueFactory setup such as

   cell.setTableValueFactory(cell -> new ValueWrapper<>(cell.getValue(), m -> m.getProperty())

Now the problems:

1. Should I worry about memory leak? There are several weak event listeners, but if they're for general use, why doesn't JavaFX wrap all listeners as weak listeners internally?
2. Update performance: Does JavaFX automatically delay/batch updates or must I enclose change event firing in beginChange() ... endChange()? If it does, I could just make all property setters to fire invalidation events and make things a lot simpler.

ObservableModel :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;

public class ObservableModel implements Observable
{
    protected final CopyOnWriteArrayList<InvalidationListener> listenerList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener)
    {
        this.listenerList.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener)
    {
        this.listenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    public void clearListeners()
    {
        this.listenerList.clear();
    }

    public void fireValueChangedEvent()
    {
        Platform.runLater(this::doFireValueChangedEvent); 
    }

    protected void doFireValueChangedEvent()
    {
        this.listenerList.forEach(lsnr -> lsnr.invalidated(this));
    }
}
```

ObservableModelList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.RandomAccess;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ObservableModelList<E> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<E>
        implements ObservableList<E>, RandomAccess
{
    private final InvalidationListener itemListener = new InvalidationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable)
            {
                int index = ObservableModelList.this.indexOf(observable);
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    ObservableModelList.this.fireChange(index);
                }
            }
        };

    private final List<E> backingList;

    public ObservableModelList()
    {
        this(new ArrayList<E>());
    }

    public ObservableModelList(List<E> list)
    {
        this.backingList = list;
        for (E e : this.backingList)
        {
            if (e instanceof Observable)
                ((Observable) e).addListener(this.itemListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index)
    {
        return this.backingList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return this.backingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o)
    {
        return this.backingList.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o)
    {
        return this.backingList.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o)
    {
        return this.backingList.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        return this.backingList.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear()
    {
        for (E e : this.backingList)
        {
            if (e instanceof Observable)
                ((Observable) e).removeListener(this.itemListener);
        }
        if (hasListeners())
        {
            beginChange();
            nextRemove(0, this);
        }
        this.backingList.clear();
        ++this.modCount;
        if (hasListeners())
        {
            endChange();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        beginChange();
        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; ++i)
        {
            remove(fromIndex);
        }
        endChange();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        beginChange();
        boolean modified = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        {
            if (c.contains(get(i)))
            {
                remove(i);
                --i;
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        endChange();
        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        beginChange();
        boolean modified = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        {
            if (!c.contains(get(i)))
            {
                remove(i);
                --i;
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        endChange();
        return modified;
    }

    public void fireChange(int index)
    {
        this.beginChange();
        this.nextUpdate(index);
        this.endChange();
    }

    public void fireChanges(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        this.beginChange();
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
            this.nextUpdate(i);
        this.endChange();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, E element)
    {
        if (element instanceof Observable)
            ((Observable) element).addListener(this.itemListener);
        this.backingList.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doSet(int index, E element)
    {
        E removed = this.backingList.set(index, element);
        if (removed instanceof Observable)
            ((Observable) removed).removeListener(this.itemListener);
        if (element instanceof Observable)
            ((Observable) element).addListener(this.itemListener);
        return removed;
    }

    @Override
    protected E doRemove(int index)
    {
        E removed = this.backingList.remove(index);
        if (removed instanceof Observable)
            ((Observable) removed).removeListener(this.itemListener);
        return removed;
    }
}
```

ValueWrapper:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.WeakInvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;

public class ValueWrapper<S extends Observable, T> extends ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<T> implements InvalidationListener
{
    protected S parent;
    protected Function<S, T> getValue;

    public ValueWrapper(S parent, Function<S, T> getValue)
    {
        super(getValue.apply(parent));
        this.parent = parent;
        this.getValue = getValue;
        parent.addListener(new WeakInvalidationListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable)
    {
        T newValue = this.getValue.apply(this.parent);
        this.setValue(newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use JavaFX properties in your model? This is the way the framework is designed to be used.

Comment: I'm still considering that. It will enable direct binding between models and UI, but wouldn't that be too heavy-weight? It'd be one object per property!